# Magnific Popup: Protocols and domains must match, YouTube video not loading in Chrome

Tags: youtube, cross-domain, magnific-popup

I'm using the Magnific Popup Responsive lightbox plugin to open a youtube video.

My code:

```
init: function() {
    $('#lightbox').magnificPopup({
      disableOn: 700,
      type: 'iframe',
      mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
      removalDelay: 160,
      preloader: false,

      fixedContentPos: false
    });
}
```

In Chrome, when I click on the link, the lightbox opens, and sometimes the video loads, and sometimes it doesn't. Most often it loads just the audio without the video.

I am given the warning "Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "[my domain]". Protocols, domains, and ports must match." - Chrome usually gives me this warning with iframes.
It is also failing to load a .swf file.

I am developing on a server, not locally fyi.

This is working fine in Safari, Firefox & IE8+; it is only having this issue in Chrome.

Comment: Please provide the link to page with issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, in Firefox and Safari as well as Chrome. I get the same error message "Protocols, domains, and ports must match." and just get a black window. On Firefox I get a Youtube play button in the window, but when clicked it simply states "an error has occurred". If I request the video from the URL (without invoking magnific popup) the video loads ok, so the URL is correct. I'm using the same code as the demo page to play the video - curious as it obviously works perfectly on your demo page. Wondering if I need a cross-domain file or something to make this possible.